# Formulae for both identifying or generating primes; Shows arranged distribution. Solved; basically trial division.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

While looking at numbers and considering $n < p < 2n - 2$ and $p = 3n\pm 1$, where $p$ is any prime number, I was able identify a property for numbers $c=3n\pm 1$ where $c$ is a composite number:

Let $P_n$ be primes where $P_1 = 3, P_2 = 5,...,P_n=p$.

Every composite $c$ in $n \to x$ is of the form:

- $P_{1 \to n}y$

or

- ${P_n }^2$

Since this is true, only $n$ primes for $P_n = \pi(\sqrt{limit})-1$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function, is needed to identify all primes $P_n < p < limit$.
In that case, the number of primes used to determine if $n=p$ are considerably less than in other functions that tests primes, and it's a bit more elegant, not brute-force, no randomness, e.g.

So it is possible that finding primes from $3,...,\infty$ could be done (had it not tended towards infinity, pun) by testing odd numbers consecutively and increasing $n$ for every $c = {P_n}^2$.

To test this, I needed a function to see if the number is of the form $3n\pm 1$:

$e_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & x\pm 1 \not\equiv 0 \: \mod\,3\\ 
1, & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then I needed to check if the number is composite based on  $P_{1 \to n}y$:

$k_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & x \equiv 0 \: \mod\,\forall\in \{ P_1,...,P_{n-1} \}\\ 
1, & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

I also needed to check if ${P_n }^2$ where $n = \pi(\sqrt{limit})-1$:

$t_n(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & x = \,({P_n}^2)\\ 
1, & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

Then I summed it all into one function:

isPrime$_n(x) = 
t_n(x) \mid k_n(x) \mid e_n(x),\,\,$ if $\,\, {\pi(\sqrt x)} = n$

Where $\mid$ is logical operator AND.

From this it's easy to create an algorithm which yields primes, and only primes, without sieving or performing complex calculations.

Example pseudo-code:

```
n = 1: Counts number of primes in use by algorithm
N = {3,5,7,9,...,limit}: All natural odd numbers from 3 to limit
P = {3}: The first odd prime number, the others found are appended

for all numbers x in set N do:
    if not t(x,n):
        n = n + 1, next
    if not k(x,n):
        next;
    if e(x,n):
        Append x to P, next
```

This yields primes and only primes.

Here's an example that uses Python to generate primes based on this principle:
(Please excuse bad formatting.)

```
def k(x,n):
    for y in range(n):
        if x%primes[y]==0:
            return False
    return True

def e(x,n):
    global primes
    def xpm(x):
        return x+1,x-1
    x = xpm(x)
    if not (x[0]%3==0 or x[1]%3==0):
            return False
    return True

def t(x,n):
    global primes
    if x!=(primes[n-1]**2):
        return True
    return False

## The number of primes used, n, is printed as n but;
## if the limit has a prime power close or at the limit,
## like 55, then n is most likely incorrect because
## the next number that is 0 MOD(primes[n-1]) is primes[n-1]*primes[n-2]

primes = [3]    ## Start with the first odd prime
n = 1           ## n is 1, since primes[n-1] == 3
                ## primes[n-1] is 2
limit  = 1000   ## The limit of numbers to test if prime

for x in range (5,limit + 1,2):  ## For all odd numbers x to limit

    if not t(x,n):          ## if x % primes[n-1] == 0, then x is composite.
        n += 1              ## Increment n, because primes[n-1]**2 was
        continue            ## encountered, then continue

    if not k(x,n):          ## if x % primes[0 -> n-1] == 0, then
        continue            ## x is composite, continue

    if not e(x,n):          ## if (x+-1) % 3 == 0, then 
        continue            ## x is composite

    primes.append(x)        ## x is prime so append it to the prime list

print ("Number of primes used to generate "+str(len(primes))+": "+str(n-1))
print ("Largest prime used: "+str(primes[n-1]))
```

Yields primes for any limit, but the code is not optimized so don't expect sieve speed, since **it is actually testing each number, not sieveing them**.

Although slow compared to good sieves, it ran and finished in < 3 seconds with $limit = 10^6$. This resulted in 78497 primes, generated from $P_1,...,P_n$ where $n = 167 = \pi(\sqrt{limit})-1$, which is the number of primes under $10^6$-1, accounting for 2.

So my question is:

**Is this well known and understood from before? In that case, where might I find more information on the topic?**

I ask because after weeks of research I have not found a function, except sieves, which doesn't exactly check numbers for primality, that needs no more than $\pi(\sqrt x)$ primes to generate a series of primes.

If I've missed an important point that makes this common knowledge, please tell me so that I may fell the sting of toiling for nothing instead of reading...

Kindest regards,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've re-discovered trial division.

Comment: You really don't see the point...

Comment: @JohnWO: I understand the algorithm perfectly well. $k_{\pi(\sqrt x)}(x)$ is precisely trial division by the primes up to $\sqrt x$. This is a useful algorithm for testing small numbers for primality, don't feel bad that you weren't the first to find it.

Comment: I'm sorry if you think I implied that you didn't.
My point was to defog the relationship between the primes, prime powers, and the product of primes.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the first step to finding Meissel's prime counting formula.

Take a look at this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: I can see no use of Bertrand's postulate in your algorithm, and the fact that all primes after 3 are one more or less than a multiple of 3 is most definitely not a result of Euler but a remarkably obvious fact stemming from the fact that they aren't divisible by 3, and there's nothing else for them to be.

Comment: I see the connection you're referencing and it makes sense, thanks.
Regarding Bertrand's postulate, it was the trail of though, as described in the question.

Comment: It's rather discourteous to delete comments when somebody else already responded without acknowledging this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the completely standard simplest way to test primality using a list of primes. I suspect it doesn't have a name, since it's simply the only thing to do. The logic is as follows; I think you've overcomplicated it by treating lots of cases separately.

- If a number $n$ is not prime, it has at least two prime factors $p,q$. Since $pq\le n$ at least one of them must be $\le \sqrt n$ or they would multiply to something bigger than $n$.

  - Therefore, a primality test working only by checking divisibility by possible factors should check all primes within $2, \cdots, \sqrt n$

For an example of the algorithm you discuss, see the end of the first paragraph of the Wikipedia article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Comment: I am not checking all primes from $2,..,\sqrt n$ but for $P_1,...,P_n$ where $n$ is $\pi (\sqrt{limit})$.

Comment: But $m=\pi(\sqrt x)$ tells you how many primes are at most $\sqrt x$ so $P_m$ is the last prime smaller than $\sqrt x$ by definition, so this is exactly the range $2,,\cdots,sqrt x$

Comment: That is not the same.
If I where to test numbers $3 -> n$ it would be considerably slower as it does not consider for powers.
I suggest you reread if you miss my point.
My code does not contain it because it was just a quick fix I put together, but it's in the comments.

It is beside the point anyway, as I wanted input on what the formula implies in terms of the relationship between the numbers and if there was any information on that subject.

Comment: I didn't say all numbers in that range, I said all primes. I have read your Python code because your language is unclear, and it is clear than your `k(x,n)` function does exactly what I have described.

Comment: I know that you said prime numbers, and that was what "numbers" was referencing in that context; "Comments" was referencing the comments in my code. Sorry the unclear language.

Comment: I have no idea week what you are trying to say, but your $k_n(x)$ function is doing exactly the test I described as far as I can see. Please tell me what it excludes testing against from the set of primes I described.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to modify your code to give your function a modifiable starting point?

What I mean by that is currently, in your code, N starts at 3 and goes up 5, 7, 9...etc., with P also starting at 3.

Could it be modified so that N started at say, 1000001 (first odd number past 1mil), and P started at 1000003 (first prime past 1mil)?

Comment: Short answer: Yes